# Why isn't a function declared as async of type types.CoroutineType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

Quote from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html):

> `types.CoroutineType`
>
> The type of coroutine objects, created by async def functions.

Quote from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-def):

> Functions defined with async def syntax are always coroutine functions, even if they do not contain await or async keywords.

Python console session:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32
bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import types
>>> def f(): pass
...
>>> async def g(): pass
...
>>> isinstance(f, types.FunctionType)
True
>>> isinstance(g, types.FunctionType)
True
>>> isinstance(g, types.CoroutineType)
False
>>>
```

Why doesn't `isinstance(g, types.CoroutineType)` evaluate to `True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between coroutine and coroutine function. The same way as there is a difference between generator and generator function:

Calling the function `g` returns a coroutine, e.g.:

```
>>> isinstance(g(), types.CoroutineType)
True
```

If you need to tell if `g` is a coroutine function (i.e. would return a coroutine) you can check with:

```
>>> from asyncio import iscoroutinefunction
>>> iscoroutinefunction(g)
True
```

Comment: Ooh, I'm a little late

Answer (score 1):

`g` by itself is not a valid Coroutine function when used that way:

```
isinstance(g, types.CoroutineType)
```

This is similar to the difference between a generator and a generator function. Instead, use `g()` to compare:

```
isinstance(g(), types.CoroutineType)
```

You could also try `iscoroutinefunction(g)` instead, much more shorter and neater:

```
from asyncio import iscoroutinefunction
iscoroutinefunction(g)   #Return true
```

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html